# JSONConvert not returning any values from list using deserializeobject function

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have code that is working on one of my aspx.cs pages but not this one. The issue is that The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is returning a list of `null` values.
This is the code

```
private async Task getProj(List<ProjectsObj> temp)
{
    using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
    {
        client1.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57578/");
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await client1.GetAsync("api/projects").ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            dynamic result = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            List<ProjectsObj> root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProjectsObj>>(result);
            foreach (ProjectsObj proj in root)
            {
                temp.Add(proj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does the response look like? `result` will be a `string` so no need for `dynamic`.

Comment: What's your object model, and what is the actual string result?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to help you, specifically the raw contents of `string result` and the data model for `ProjectsObj`.  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.  Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*